# Multiple print functions in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

The goal of this post is to put multiple print functions throughout a list comprehension to visually understand what's happening within.

Important notes:

- This **should not** be used for anything other than educational purposes and trying to understand code.
- If you are using Python 2.x, you need to add a future import (it's in the code I pasted) or else print won't work. Only functions work in list comprehension. Print in 2.x does not operate as a function. Or...just switch to Python 3.x.

This was the original question:

```
    ## Using future to switch Print to a function
    from __future__ import print_function 

    reg = []
    for x in [1,2,3]:
        for y in [3,1,4]:
            print('looping through',x,'then',y)
            if x == y:
                print('success',x,y)
                reg.append((x,y))
    print(reg)
```

Here's the equivalent list comprehension with no print statements.

```
    from __future__ import print_function 
    comp = [(x,y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x == y] 
    print(comp)
```

So is there any way to put in a bunch of print statements so both code print the same things?

---

#### Edit with solution to original question:

Using the methods in the comments - I've figured it out!

So say you want to convert this.

```
    from __future__ import print_function 

    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 1
    n = 2

    [[a,b,c] for a in range(x+1) for b in range(y+1) for c in range(z+1) if a + b + c != n]
```

Adding print statements to print each loop, showing if it failed or not.

```
    from __future__ import print_function 

    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 1
    n = 2

    [
        [a,b,c] for a in range(x+1) for b in range(y+1) for c in range(z+1) if 
        (print('current loop is',a,b,c) or a + b + c != n)
        and
        (print('condition true at',a,b,c) or True)
    ]
```

So really the only thing that was changed was the conditional at the end.

```
    (a + b + c != n)
```

to

```
    (print('current loop is',a,b,c) or a + b + c != n)
    and
    (print('condition true at',a,b,c) or True)
```

---

#### Additional Information:

So there's good stuff in the comment section that I think would help others as well. I'm a visual learner so this website was great.

- http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/#colored-comprehension

(credits to Tadhg McDonald-Jensen)

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side effects, such as printing things.

Comment: If you can't glance at a list comprehension and understand what's happening, you shouldn't be using that list comprehension (use a explicit loop instead).

Comment: I'm not actually writing any code - I would need this when I'm reading code from advanced coders.

Comment: Then use a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Debugger? I'm using Sublime Text 3. Does that have...debugger?

Comment: Sublime Text is great, but for a nice debugger experience, try [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/starting-the-debugger-session.html).

Comment: Wait a minute... @jhub1 if you are only applying this when trying to understand code written by someone else then why are you not just converting the list comprehension into the longhand loop you started with? I feel like that would be significantly more helpful then making the original code harder to read so it can print out some extra stuff.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I've been working on. I'm converting someone else's list comprehension into longhand loop. My attempt to use print in other people's list comprehension was an attempt understand what's going on so that I could convert that to longhand loop.

Comment: If you want to understand the relationship (and conversion) between longhand loops and comprehension there are [great resources](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/#colored-comprehension) to visually see how the two relate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate your `print` function, but the return value isn't useful since it's always `None`. You can use `and`/`or` to combine it with another expression.

```
comp = [(x,y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if (print('looping through',x,'then',y) or x == y) and (print('success', x, y) or True)]
```

I really hope you're only doing this for educational purposes, because it's ugly as heck. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: of the three answers posted, this is the only one that actually answers the question asked of "is there any way to put in a bunch of print statements so both code print the same things?".  Odd that @jhub1 accepted BPL's answer that doesn't actually print the same stuff.

Comment: i stand corrected. no one mentioned anything wrong in that long discussion so i accepted it figuring it to be the closest to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think you shouldn't running debug code inside list comprehensions, that said, if you wanted to do so, you could wrap your code inside a function like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function


def foo(x, y):
    print('looping through', x, 'then', y)
    if x == y:
        print('success', x, y)
        return (x, y)

comp = [foo(x, y) for x in [1, 2, 3] for y in [3, 1, 4] if x == y]
print(comp)
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension was introduced with [PEP 202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) which states:

> It is proposed to allow conditional construction of list literals
>   **using for and if clauses.**  They would nest in the same way for loops
>   and if statements nest now.

List comprehension was designed to replace constructs that formed a list using only `for` loops, `if` conditionals and `.append` method once per iteration.  Any additional structure is not possible in list comprehensions so unless you stuck your prints into one of the allowed components you cannot add them.

That being said, putting a print statement in the conditional - while technically possible - is highly **not** recommended.

```
[a for a in x if print("this is a bad way to test",a)]
```

Comment: Yup I tried this actually - it would be useful if I could retain the original conditional, and also add on a print statement...and as a bonus, add print elsewhere to, to see what happens elsewhere.

Comment: the whole point of my answer is that **you can't add extra print statements** because that is not how list comprehension works. and you shouldn't add print statements like the code I am showing..